# Haskell function to error-diffuse a floating value to a list of integers

Tags: haskell

I needed to write a function which would 'error diffuse' floating values to integers:

```
errorDiffuse :: Double -> Int -> Double -> [Int]

errorDiffuse _ 0   _   = []

errorDiffuse v num err = tv : errorDiffuse v (num - 1) (err + v - fromIntegral tv)
  where tv = truncate (v + err)
```

So that, for example:

```
errorDiffuse 1.4 10 0 => [1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1]
```

(i.e., the function produces a list of `num` integers, each of which is the ceiling or floor of `v`, starting with a given error value (zero in this case)).

**Is there a better way to write this sort of `for` loop? What's the higher-order function I ought to be thinking in terms of?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'd get rid of the dependency on `num`, since that's just a counter,
and you can use `take num` on an infinite list of `errorDiffuses`:

```
errorDiffuses :: Double -> Double -> [Int]
errorDiffuses v err = tv : errorDiffuses v (err + v - fromIntegral tv)
 where
  tv = truncate (v + err)
```

So we have:

```
errorDiffuse' :: Double -> Int -> Double -> [Int]
errorDiffuse' v num err = take num $ errorDiffuses v err
```

Then I'd think about generating the list of `errorDiffuses` differently.
Since we're trying to generate a list, that makes me think of `unfolds`,
which you can find in Data.List:

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

The unfold takes a function that, given a seed, produces the next
value in the outputted list, along with a new seed. The function
starts with an intitial seed, and keeps using those seeds, adding to the
list until the function returns `Nothing`.

The function we're looking for is the following:

```
nextErrorDiffuse :: Double -> Double -> Maybe (Int, Double)
nextErrorDiffuse v err = Just (tv, err + v - fromIntegral tv)
 where
  tv = truncate (v + err)
```

Our list is infinite, so we always return a `Just` value. The value that is output at each stage is `tv`, and the next "seed" is given by `err + v - fromIntegral tv`.

Putting things together we have:

```
errorDiffuse'' :: Double -> Int -> Double -> [Int]
errorDiffuse'' v num err = take num $ unfoldr (nextErrorDiffuse v) err
```

Comment: Fantastic, thankyou! I don't think `unfoldr` is in my mental toolkit yet but it was exactly the sort of thing I was thinking of.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Comment: `unfoldr` is a great tool to add to your toolkit. Whenever you need to produce a list from some seed value(s), `unfoldr` should come to mind.